# What does Harley Quinn mean by, "Him, too"?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, birds-of-prey

In *Birds of Prey And the Fantabulous Emancipation of One Harley Quinn* (2019), the Huntress kills Happy, the victim of facial cosmetic vandalism, and cops surrounded Harley Quinn:

> Harley Quinn: They're shooting arrows now? Ah, crap. **Him, too**?

What does Harley Quinn mean by, "Him, too"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't the police, those are Roman Sionis' goons. The next time we see Harley (chronologically speaking) is at timestamp 41:40, surrounded by the same thugs, being held in Roman's basement under the Black Mask club.

The "him" that she's referring to would be Roman himself.

[image: Harley tied to a chair surrounded by thugs]